# Prove that $\frac{n-a}{n} < \frac{n+1-a}{n+1}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, fractions

I have this math question that I'm kind of stuck on.

> Prove that $\frac{n-a}{n} < \frac{n+1-a}{n+1}$

So far I have that: $\frac{n-a}{n} < \frac{n+1-a}{n+1} = n-a < \frac{n(n+1-a)}{n(n+1)} = n-\frac{n(n+1-a)}{n(n+1)} < a$

However, I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks

Comment: $a$ is any real number and $n$ is any positive integer

Comment: $\frac{n-a}{n}=1-\frac{a}{n}$ and $\frac{n+1-a}{n+1}=1-\frac{a}{n+1}$, so the inequality is equivalent to $\frac{a}{n+1}<\frac{a}{n}$.

Comment: Simply multiply denominators (I suppose that $a,n > 0$), and you get the trivial inequality $$-a < 0$$

Comment: $a$ must be positive for this inequality to hold.

Comment: I think you mean $a \in \mathbb{R^+}$ because this is obviously not true for $a = 0$ and it just takes looking at it for a second to see its not true for $a < 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac {n-a}n = 1 - \frac a n < 1-\frac a{n+1}=\frac{n+1-a}{n+1}$$

Comment: How does this work for any real number $a$ and positive integer $n$?

Comment: It works only for $a>0$.

Comment: For $a<0$, the inequality becomes opposite.